# CreateView and ListView from different apps on the same page.

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I have two different apps, recipe and comment.

I have a DetailView in the recipe app which points to `url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', RecipeDetailView.as_view(), name='recipe-detail')` which is also in the recipe app url file.

I also have a CreateView in my views.py file in my comment app. How can i put this CreateView which is in my comment app into the same url that is shown above? Do I do this in the template? Or do I do this in the recipe views.py or urls.py file?

I have had no problems making views with one app, i am getting tripped up trying to show views across apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, forget about apps here; they have nothing to do with anything. An app is just a collection of models and views, it has no relationship to what can be shown on a page.

Your issue is that a single view is exclusively responsible for rendering a page. Django calls a view in response to a request at a particular URL, and whatever is returned from there becomes the content of the page. There is no way to call multiple views from a URL.

Instead, you need to think about constructing your code in such a way that the view renders content from multiple places. There are various ways of doing this, such as including templates, using template tags or context processors, composing class-based views, etc.

Comment: i was wondering if this was a django limitation, thank you for the response i will look into the other things that you have suggested.